# Hadoop returns only a key value pair

Tags: hadoop

Hadoop returns only a key value pair.  Can't I get a full document?  One value by itself, doesn't seem useful.  Is there a software tool to get the whole document?

Answer (score 0):

Use Sequences file. In sequence file input format, you can get whole document/single file as value. Key would be the name of the document.